# How can one use T-SQL to select only those rows that have column B Value not greater than the next greater values in column A?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
A     B
1     2
1     1
1     3
1     4
3     3
3     4
4     5
```

How can one use T-SQL to select only those rows that have column B value not greater than the next greater values in column A?

For example, if above table is the input, the output should be as follows;

```
A     B
1     2
1     1
3     3
4     5
```

Comment: How do you define ***next row*** in your data? There's nothing I see that you could order your result by ... (no `ID` or `DateTimeStamp` column to use for `ORDER BY`)

Comment: The next value in column A refers to values greater than the current row's value. A and B are table fields you could use to order by.

Comment: Wouldn't `3     4` and `1     3` be included?

Comment: @marc Next ***row*** was never mentioned. The question specifically stated *next greater values*. Could have been phrased better, but no reference to *row*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select t1.A, t1.B
  from tbl t1
 where t1.B < isnull((select min(t2.A)
                        from tbl t2
                       where t2.A > t1.A), t1.B+1)
```